# Android connect to servlets that is on cloud server

Tags: android, servlets, openshift

I have my server and servlets set up on openshift redhat server. I have an android application that needs to use these servlets.

Normally on localhost the ipaddress in android would look like this

`http://10.0.2.2:8080/SRD/`

but now I want it to connect to cloud server so I tried:

`http://xxx-caffeinepowered.rhcloud.com:8080/SRD/`

but that's not working. What should the address be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUst drop the 8080 from your url and it should work. We redirect all http traffic over port 80

Comment: yup, realised that 5mins after posting the question, thanks:)